# Searching a Generic Range for a Member with a Specific Field

Tags: c++, templates, template-function

that is my template-function:

```
template<class DataStruct>
    static bool isPlayerIn(DataStruct players, int id){
        for(DataStruct::iterator player = players.begin();
                player != players.end(); ++player){
            if((*player)->_id == id){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I want it to be able to get players as vector and as map, or any other STL. I cant use the algorithm find, because I'm searching for a "player", who's inner field id is the same as the given parameter. Is there any way to this work ?

It complaines about:

```
(*player)->_id
```

Because it doesn't know that player is a ptr to ptr to Player class.

Comment: Or maybe I can use this case find_if?

Comment: I would use `std::find_if`

Comment: you could explicitly cast as a Player class pointer (probably, didnt check)

Comment: find_if isn't good here because the function of it  needs 2 parameters:

bool isSameId(Player* player, int id){
  return player->_id == id;
 }

I'll check the explicit cast.

Comment: Ok, the explicit cast is not a bad idea, but how do I make the iterator declaration correct in the for: DataStruct::iterator.
Is there a template for iterator or something ?

Comment: seems like typename DataStruct::iterator works, is it correct this case?

Comment: you could pass the id to `std::find_if` as part of a lambda `find_if(begin(players), end(players), [id](auto player) { return player->_id == id;});`

Comment: Yes you need `typename` here, as the compiler cannot know that `DataStruct::iterator` is a type, as `DataStruct` is a template argument.

Comment: ok, about the second solution without find_if, there is a probem in my case because if I pass a map, I need to do .second for the Player*, so it's pretty a problem to do a generic template that will suit also for a map, so find_if is the best solution here.

About the find_if solution, that's interesting, can I do it writing this whole code into a function "IsSameId" or I must write it as you suggested, bsruth ?

Comment: bsruth, can you write your answer detaily as an answer down below, how do I write correctfully this thing with lambda

Comment: oh well, someone beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for it, you could put the lambda in an `isSameID` function if it will be used in multiple places. It would also probably make it a little easier to read when you get to code maintenance.

```
template <class ContType>
bool isSameID(ContType cont, int id) {
    auto found = find_if(begin(cont), end(cont), [id] (auto item) {
        return item->_id == id;
    });
   return found != end(cont);
}
```

This function assumes that container is passed and you're using c++14.

**Update 1:**
The quickest way to make it work for both `map` and `vector` would be to just separate out the `_id` retrieval from the function and let the compiler choose the right way to get the `_id` for a given container type. I've also removed `auto` per your request and switched to passing the container by `const&` to avoid making copies:

```
    int GetID(const pair<int, Player*>& item) {
        return item.second->_id;
    }
    int GetID(Player* item) {
        return item->_id;
    }

    template <class ContType>
        bool isSameID(const ContType& cont, int id) {
            typename ContType::const_iterator found = find_if(begin(cont), end(cont),
               [id] (typename ContType::value_type item) {
                return GetID(item) == id;
            });
           return found != end(cont);
        }
```

Comment: How can I avoid using auto (as I know it need a unique flag when compiling as auto and I don't want to use it) ? 
As i understand, writing the concrete type will do the work: Player* in my case

Comment: And in this case, is there any solution for map container, because it containes pairs? It would work for vectro, deque and that stuff, but for a map that is a real mess, isn't it?
Do you see more generic solution, that would work for vector and for map both ?

Comment: what is the type of your map?

Comment: <int, Player *>, so the I need in map case pair.second->getId() == id. I've opened a new question, but if we'll handle it here, it would be excellent and i'll post the answer there or if you want to answer in a new topic: stackoverflow.com/questions/34858435/merging-two-function-into-one-template-function-comitable-with-vector-and-map-co

Answer (score 1):

Using C++11, you can easily use [`find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) with a [lambda function](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html):

```
[=](const typename DataStruct::value_type &v){return v._id == id;}
```

where altogether you'd use something like

```
auto has_id = [=](const typename DataStruct::value_type &v){return v._id == id;};

return std::find_if(
    std::begin(players),
    std::end(players),
    has_id) != std::end(players);
```

Comment: Yes, that exactly I'm looking for, but I don't understand the typename DataStruct, and another thing, if I dont want to use auto, can I just write bool instead ?

Comment: You can't write ``bool``, since its type is a lambda function, which is entirely different.

Comment: As I see this solution is bad for map container type, which contains pairs and the second of the pair is my "v" as you wrote it. Any solution to make it compatible with map container ?

Comment: Well, if you're asking how to write a function that works for both pair types (e.g., ``map``) and "normal" range types, then it *can* be done, but is significantly more complicated. If the question is *only* about map types, then in the lambda you'd simply use `.first`/`.second` as needed.

Comment: Ok, yes, I though it would be complicated, so the solution for map and vector for example is two overloaded functions, which will be called each one at the relevant case, right ?

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of a separate question. I suggest you open one for it. SO is not really built for a dialog in comments.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem withe your encapsulation, since the function dos not know what DataStruct is, it cannot directly de-reference an internal iterator of it.
if you implemente a de-reference operator for iterator it will work.

in the iterator add:

```
objStored *operator(){
    return **this;
}
```

then in your player obj add a method to get the id:

```
int getId(){
return this->id;
}
```

and instead  of `(*player)->_id == id` write `(*player)->getId()`

this way any class that have in iterator that holds(in any way) an object that support(in any way) the getId method will work.

if you use templates to create a general function, you shouldn't make it so it will only work for a  class that have an iterator that is a pointer to a pointer to players that have an _id member. 
try to assume less about your objects.